# Npgsql - generation ddl scripts from Entity Framework's data model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ddl, npgsql

I've crated a data model in VS 2010 and now I want to generate a DDL scripts for my PostgreSQL database. I've registered a Npgsql provider in the .NET 4.0 profile machine.config file and created proper connection string in app.config file but still I cannot find a Npgsql provider on a provider's list when I'm trying to write model to database.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Npgsql doesn't have support for vs.net 2010 design time. You will need to use edmgen command line tool. Sorry for that... :(

Comment: Ok, but I'm afraid that edmgen doesn't work this way. AFAIK it allows to generate data model from the database schema but I want to generate the database schema from data model. I'd be thankful if you show me how to use edmgen in my case. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not think that you will be able to generate a script for the database by using Npgsql.

The root of the support for creating a database script is the [`DbServicesProvider.CreateDatabaseScript`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/DbProviderServices.cs,8c1b3c943deafaa3) method. However, the Npgsql implementation of the abstract class, [`NpgsqlServices`](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/2.2/Npgsql.EntityFramework/NpgsqlServices.cs), does not override `DbCreateDatabaseScript` method, which means that it cannot generate a SQL script.